# RSpec - Different behavior for variable for single run versus suite

Tags: rspec

Is this intended behavior? If so, is there a way around it?

Rspec is marking a describe as passed but not running not running a called def inside of the describe statement when I run the suite/do not specify an *.rb file to run. Said describe statement is in my spec_helper.rb file
However, when I specify a file to run, it does run the body of the describe statement and all it's called definitions.

I would expect these two scenarios to have the same behavior.

```
describe 'Setting up environment from a tag' do
    it 'Is prod', env_prod: true do
        MyEnv = setupEnvironment('prod')
    end
    it 'Is local', env_local: true do
        MyEnv = setupEnvironment('local')
    end
    it 'Is Q', env_q: true do
      MyEnv = setupEnvironment('q')
      puts "setupEnviroment = " + MyEnv.fetch('navPointURL')
    end
    it 'Is Stage', env_stage: true do
      MyEnv = setupEnvironment('stage')
    end
end

def setupEnvironment(envName)
    puts "setupEnvironment was called with #{envName}"
    if (envName == "local")
        tmpEnv = {
        "kioskURL" => "http://kioskdev.local"
         }
    elsif (envName == 'prod')
        tmpEnv= {
          "kioskURL" => "http://kiosk.conductix.net/"
          }
    elsif(envName == "stage")
          tmpEnv = {
          "kioskURL" => "http://kiosks.conductix.net/"
          }
    elsif (envName == "q")
          tmpEnv = {
          "kioskURL" => "http://kioskq.conductix.net/"
          }
    end
    return tmpEnv
end
```

The "MyEnv" hash is empty on the suite run, even though "Is Q" or "Is Prod" are marked as passed tests.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm kind of confused with what you are trying to do here. Why are you defining tests within spec_helper.rb? ... that's generally used for configuration. Why are you defining test that don't actually test anything - they are simply invoking your setupEnvironment method, so yes they will pass irrespective of what is happening inside setupEnvironment. Why are you testing for different environments (eg, production)?

Comment: in addition you are fetching `navPointURL` which you haven't even declared in your hash so I'm surprised that one passes at all ... it should have raised a `key not found` error

Comment: I removed the navPointURL and several other keys to be more concise. (In fact the failure message is "key not found" when it fails/running no specific file.)

I want to be able to use a tag to set the Hash values for the environment. Some tests don't need to run in prod or can't run in the local environment. I tried making MyEnv into an environment variable in side said tests, and that didn't work either. I've yet to see a good solution for this; I've spent days digging stack overflow and Google.

Comment: but to run tests in production environment doesn't seem like a good idea at all ... after all you shouldn't be deploying to production **until** you are confident that you haven't broken anything. Are you sure you can't mock out calls for tests so that they can run in the local environment - that would seem a better strategy than committing code that is potentially breaking things and testing elsewhere. FWIW ... I did copy your code into my spec_helper.rb and ran rspec and rspec spec/models/some_model.rb and it output from setupEnvironment in both cases.

Comment: Are you calling setupEnvironment directly, or are you calling the MyEnv variable? The MyEnv variable is being instantiated, but not filled when I run just `rspec -t env_q` or `env_prod`, etc.

Comment: There were two functions named "setupEnvironment" in the suite. They were conflicting with one another and causing this issue for me.

Comment: I had copied exactly what you posted and placed it in my spec_helper.rb - didn't do any more than that. From your last comment does that mean you don't have an issue any more?

Comment: David, you're correct. This was user error.